# Can't seem to convert if..else to try..catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch

would anyone be able to help me to convert this code into a try- catch function?

```
document.getElementById("find").click();
window.setInterval(function() {
  if (document.getElementById("bba")) {
    document.getElementById("bba").click(); 
  } else {
    document.getElementById("find").click();
  }
}, 1000);
```

basically, I want it to click the bba button when that button is available, but being that the button only pops up at certain time, (when my grade gets submitted) the entire code doesn't run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: there is no do-while?

Comment: seems to be the same code as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798375/jscript-gives-me-appendto-not-a-function-even-though-its-not-in-my-code but with a different question

Comment: @JaromandaX- you're right it's and if-else. My mistake :(

Comment: @JaromandaX- it is the same question- I researched a way to solve it (try-catch)but seem to have trouble implementing it. I would love some help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would do the trick

```
document.getElementById("find").click();
window.setInterval(function() {
  try {
      document.getElementById("bba").click(); 
  } catch(e) {
      document.getElementById("find").click();
  }
}, 1000);
```

However, that really doesn't change the underlying logic - so not sure how this helps

Comment: thank you so much! you're right it doesn't work. But my question is why. I don't understand Why it wouldn't press find if the the other button isn't available. I guess jscript is harder than it looks. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use *try..catch* for anything where alternative logic is available. Writing code that you *know* will throw an error is like parking your car by feel.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with *if..else* or similar constructs, consider:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  (document.getElementById("bba") || document.getElementById("find")).click();
}, 1000);
```

which will not throw errors provided *bba* sometimes exists and *find* always exists.